# Jquery Options using $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scope

I'm trying to write a jquery plugin and i have a question about the famous "this".

Here is the call of the custom plugin :

```
$('.selector').myPlugin({
        test: $(this).attr('rel')
});
```

And now, somewhere in my plugin :

```
$.myPlugin = function (options) {
    alert(options.test);
}
```

My question is : How can i use the Rel attribute of my selector in the plugin using $(this)?

The previous code is always telling me that "this" is the Document.

Thanx a lot

Comment: Could you illustrate it in http://jsfiddle.net please?

Comment: Be carefully when using 'this', because it changes based on the context ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this)` isn't what you expect it to be in that object literal. Loop using `each`:

```
$('.selector').each(function() {
    $(this).myPlugin({
        test: $(this).attr('rel')
    });
});
```

Inside `each`, `this` will point to the correct element, as opposed to the context of the calling function.

Comment: Thank you a lot this worked fine. Is there any solution to use `$(this)`  without using `each()` ?